# Insertar datos con PHP a BD Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, servidor

he empezado a aprender PHP hace relativamente poco y en el proceso estoy intentando insertar los datos de un formulario en una base de datos mediante PHP segun he estado mirando una forma segura es mediante sentencias preparadas y objetos y asi lo estoy intentando aunque nose si es la forma correcta os adjunto el codigo de insercion de datos.

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$codLibro=$_POST['codLibro'];
$importe=$_POST['importe'];
$tipoMoneda=$_POST['tipoMoneda'];

$peticion="INSERT INTO ejemplares (codLibro,importe,tipoMoneda) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($peticion);
$stmt->bind_param('dds', $codLibro, $importe, $tipoMoneda);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

echo "Registro Insertado";
$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Aqui les pongo mi fichero PHP  de conexion a la Base de datos

A continuacion este es mi formulario de envio de datos en HTML

```
<form action="addejemplares.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-2">

            <label for="codLibro">codLibro:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codLibro" id="codLibro">
            <label for="importe">importe:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="importe" id="importe">
            <label for="tipoMoneda">tipoMoneda:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tipoMoneda" id="tipoMoneda">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Como veis un simple formulario de envió y a continuación os adjunto una imagen de la tabla a la que quiero insertar datos [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por ultimo les adjunto una imagen de los errores que me esta sacando el PHP [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ante todo muchas gracias de ante mano a toda la comunidad.

**Conexión**

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bdBiblioteca");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die("No se puede conectar a la base de datos:" . mysqli_connect_error());
}else{

    echo "conexion exitosa";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Coloca el código de archivo conexion.php, el error puede surgir desde la conexion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En tu archivo "conexion.php" después de crear la conexión la estas cerrando.

Después, en el otro archivo php, donde incluyes "conexion.php" estas usando la variable $conn, en la línea 14 por eso da ese error.

No cierres la conexión en tu archivo "conexion.php",
elimina esta línea o comentala: `$conn->close();`

Creo que es este el error, puedes mirar este ejemplo en la documentación de PHP
y es lo mismo que tu tienes [Example #1 Object oriented style](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.
Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias era que estaba cerrando la conexion al parece te lo agradezco! un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Si sólo es por pruebas esta bien enviar directo el valor que contiene POST, pero sería bueno ir informándose de como "limpiar" POST para prevenir ataques XSS con htmlentities.

http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: `htmlentities` no es la solución y sigue siendo un riesgo. Por favor lee [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18233/127)

Comment: Es solo por pruebas pero muchas gracias por la informacion.

Comment: Hola @Mariano gracias, ya había leído sobre lo que me mandas a leer, y no le mencioné eso por que él ya lo aplica si ves su ejemplo. Saludos.