# Insertar datos de HTML sobre una BDD en mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

tengo una consulta en html y necesito que al pulsar el botón submit ejecute una función de php, cuyo funcionamiento es insertar los datos capturados en una base de datos de mysql.
Gracias de antemano.

Adjunto Archivos:

Consulta de HTML:

```
<form method="GET">
   ID<br>
   <input type="number" name="id">

   <input type="submit" name="boton">
</form>
```

Codigo php:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO JORNADAS (ID) VALUES ($id)";

if (mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2)) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conexion);
}
```

Comment: añade el atributo `action=codigoqueinserta.php` al form, hay un ejemplo en las relacionadas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/25432/81450

Answer (score 1):

**Con recarga de página**

Si lo quieres poner en la misma página puedes poner

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
  ...
}
```

Esto ejecuta el código después de recargar la página (cosa que hace por defecto cuando haces un submit).

Si lo que quieres es tener el php en otra página puedes poner
**(*Esta respuesta esta sacada de los comentarios*)**

```
<form method="GET" action="codigoqueinserta.php">
```

Con un ejemplo en es.stackoverflow.com/q/25432/81450

**Sin recarga de página**

Necesitaras poner utilizar `AJAX` y enviar la información a un fichero separado.